# Lazy Evaluation Problem - Functions within a tibble

Tags: r

**The Set Up**

I will be using tibble() from tidyverse in this example to store functions.

Say I have the following tibble (this is a tibble of different functions),

```
cost.matrix <- tibble(cost = c(function(x){0}, function(x){0}, function(x){NA}, function(x){x^2}, function(x){(3/2)*x},  function(x){x}),
                           flow = c(function(alpha,beta){(1/2)-alpha},function(alpha,beta){(1/2)-beta},  function(alpha,beta){NA}, function(alpha,beta){alpha},  function(alpha,beta){beta},
                                    function(alpha, beta){1-alpha-beta}))
```

for example,

```
cost.matrix$cost
# and
cost.matrix$flow
```

will list all of the functions.

Now I want to create a new column, which is composing the flow and the cost functions, for example,

```
function(x){x^2}  
# and
function(alpha, beta){1-alpha-beta}
# The new function will be
function(alpha, beta){(1-alpha-beta)^2}
```

So to do this, I use a simple for loop (If anyone has a better suggestion please let me know, had trouble vectorising the following composition function), and used this composition function on each row:

```
Composite <- function(f,g) function(...) f(g(...))
```

So now our code looks like the following(we make a new column, then use a for loop to replace the corresponding element with the composition from the cost and flow columns):

```
data <- cost.matrix %>%
  mutate(cost.flow.comp = cost)
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  a <- data$cost[[i]]
  b <- data$flow[[i]]
  want <- Composite(a,b)
  data$cost.flow.comp[[i]] <- want
}
```

**The Problem**

If we run the following code, we should now get 25:

```
data$cost.flow.comp[[4]](5,2)
```

as the relevant functions are:

```
function(x){x^2}
# and
function(alpha, beta){alpha}
```

But we get -6, because every element in the cost.flow.comp column has actually been assigned to the composition of the following functions:

```
function(x){x}
function(alpha,beta){1-alpha-beta}
```

**The Solution**
I found a fix to this problem, and it is to call the function, after it has been composed, each time in the for loop. For example (we call the want function after we assign it the composition):

```
data <- cost.matrix %>%
  mutate(cost.flow.comp = cost)
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  a <- data$cost[[i]]
  b <- data$flow[[i]]
  want <- Composite(a,b)
  want(1,1)
  data$cost.flow.comp[[i]] <- want
}
```

**The Question**

What I can't find is why this is happening? I assume a scoping characteristic I don't understand?

Just for the readers interest, the use case for this approach is representing a network with flows and costs. And wanting to do operations with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with lazy evaluation rather than scoping.  The problem is that the `Composite` function never evaluates `f` or `g`, it just creates a function that has those names as part of its body. Their value isn't fixed until the first call.  It's hard to figure out where the values actually come from to explain the -6, but the fix is easy:  change `Composite` to

```
Composite <- function(f, g) {
  force(f)
  force(g)
  function(...) f(g(...))
}
```

and then your original version works.

```
> data <- cost.matrix %>%
+   mutate(cost.flow.comp = cost)
> for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
+   a <- data$cost[[i]]
+   b <- data$flow[[i]]
+   want <- Composite(a,b)
+   data$cost.flow.comp[[i]] <- want
+ }
> data$cost.flow.comp[[4]](5,2)
[1] 25
```

By the way, I suspect there's a more functional way to create the `cost.flow.comp` column, but I don't know the `tidyverse` stuff.  I'd do it using `mapply`, i.e.

```
data$new.column <- mapply(Composite, data$cost, data$flow)
```

Comment: I have changed the title accordingly. I agree, your mapply method is much nicer. Thank you. I believe the -6 comes from the functions in the last row of the tibble, but I agree, it's still a mystery as to why that function does evaluate, maybe it's because the path or something gets overwritten every time the loop iterates, and results in the path of the last composition of functions being applied to every row. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The tidyverse counterpart to `mapply` is going to be found in the `help(pmap, pac=purrr)` help page.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden: For an explanation of lazy evaluation in R, see section 4.3.3 "Argument evaluation" in the R Language Definition manual.